# Proving $1 <\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin x}{x} d x < \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I would be grateful if you could help me prove the following inequality:

$$
1 < \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin x}{x} d x < \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Note that we can split the integral into two parts:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin x}{x} d x & =\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin x}{x} d x+\int_\pi^{2 \pi} \frac{\sin x}{x} d x \\
& =\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin x}{x} d x+\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin (x+\pi)}{x+\pi} d x \\
& =\int_0^\pi\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+\pi}\right) \sin x d x \\
& =\pi \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin x}{x(x+\pi)} d x 
\end{aligned}
$$

Unfortunately, I am currently stuck and I am not sure how to proceed with the proof. Any help or comments on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The fact that $f(x)=-x/\pi+1 \geq \frac{\pi \sin x}{x (x + \pi)}$ for $x\in [0,\pi]$ might be quite helpful

Comment: @unicornki if you find another solution can you please share?

Comment: @JoseJimenez,I'm sorry, but I won't be able to share another solution since I don't have any further insights on the probelm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove the left inequality, we use the fact that $\sin(x)\geq \frac{2x}{\pi}$ if
$x\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ and $\sin(x)\geq \frac{2(\pi -x)}{\pi}$ if
$x\in\left[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right]$, hence
\begin{align}
\pi \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin x}{x(x+\pi)} dx &\geq \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{2x}{x(x+\pi)}dx
+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\frac{2(\pi-x)}{x(x+\pi)}dx \\
&=\ln\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)+\ln\left(\frac{81}{64}\right)\approx 1.046 > 1. \tag{1}
\end{align}
To prove the right inequality, we use the fact that $\sin(x)\leq\frac{4x(\pi - x)}{\pi^2}$ if $x\in[0,\pi]$, hence
\begin{align}
\pi \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin x}{x(x+\pi)} dx &\leq \frac{4}{\pi}
\int_0^{\pi}\frac{x(\pi-x)}{x(x+\pi)}dx \\
&=4\left(2\ln 2 - 1\right) \approx 1.545 < \frac{\pi}{2}. \tag{2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Using my favored $1,400^+$ years old approximation of the sine function
$$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}\qquad \text{for} \qquad 0\leq x\leq\pi$$
$$\pi \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin (x)}{x(x+\pi)}\, d x \simeq  \pi\int_0^\pi \frac{16 (\pi -x)}{(x+\pi ) \left(5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x\right)}\,dx  $$
The antiderivative is simple after partial fraction decomposition
$$\int \frac{16 (\pi -x)}{(x+\pi ) \left(5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x\right)}\,dx =$$ $$-\frac{4 \left(4 \log \left(4 x^2-4 \pi  x+5 \pi ^2\right)-8 \log (x+\pi
   )+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{4 (x+\pi )}{7 \pi -6 x}\right)\right)}{13 \pi
   }$$ Then, for the definite integral
$$\pi \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin (x)}{x(x+\pi)}\, d x \simeq  \frac 4{13}\left(8 \log (2)+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)-\tan^{-1}(8)\right)=1.42089$$ while the exact value is $\text{Si}(2 \pi )=1.41815$ and $\frac \pi 2=1.5708$.

Comment: You have computed that the integral is *approximately* $1.42089$. Without an explicit error estimate this does not prove the inequalities.

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate the OP's work of converting the integrand to a non-negative quantity.

The way to solve this problem, provided that one is not equipped with heavy-handed approximations, is to use the "best" approximation in each possible subdomain.

In this case, consider $$
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\pi \sin x}{x(x+\pi)}dx
$$

Here, we have three domains : the first consists of the end near $x=0$, the second of a part near $x=\pi$ and the third of the rest. A well known inequality is that $\sin y \leq y$ for all $y \geq 0$, derived for example using the mean value theorem, since $\frac{\sin y - \sin 0}{y-0} = \cos(\xi)$ for some $\xi \in (0,y)$ but $\cos(\xi) \leq 1$ for all $\xi$, hence we are done.

Since $\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin y}{y} = 1$, we know that this inequality is tight. So let's apply it on both the ends :
$$
\sin x \leq x \quad\forall x \in [0,1]\\
\sin x = \sin(\pi-x) \leq (\pi-x)\quad \forall x \in [\pi-1,\pi]
$$
For the middle domain $[1,\pi-1]$, let's just use the bound $\sin x \leq 1$. We are led to the upper bound $$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\pi}{x+\pi}dx + \int_{1}^{\pi}\frac{\pi}{x(x+\pi)}dx + \int_{\pi-1}^{\pi} \frac{\pi(\pi-x)}{x(x+\pi)}dx
$$

These integrals are not complicated once you recognize that $\frac{\pi}{x(x+\pi)} = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+\pi}$. Hence, the upper bound equals $$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\pi}{x+\pi}dx + \int_{1}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{x} - \int_{1}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{x+\pi} + \int_{\pi-1}^{\pi} \frac{\pi-x}{x}dx - \int_{\pi-1}^{\pi} \frac{\pi-x}{x+\pi}dx
$$
One can compute all these integrals using the obvious antiderivative and get an upper bound of $\approx 1.49$.

---

The lower bound requires us to invert the inequality $\sin x \leq x$ in some way. We will do precisely that.

Indeed, consider that $\sin x$ is a function whose behavior we know on $[0,\pi]$. It rises from $0$ monotonically, hits $1$ at $\pi/2$ and is symmetric about $\pi/2$. In particular, we know that $\sin x \geq \frac 12$ whenever $x \geq [\frac{\pi}{6},\pi-\frac{\pi}{6}]$. This is a "middle piece" lower bound.

On the other hand, the mean value theorem for $y \in (0,\pi/6)$ tells us that $\frac{\sin y-\sin 0}{y-0} = \cos(\xi)$ for some $\xi \in (0,y)$, but $\cos(\xi) \geq \cos(\pi/6) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Therefore, $\sin y \geq \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}y$ for all $y \in [0,\frac{\pi}{6}]$. Similarly, the bound $\sin y \geq \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}(\pi-y)$ holds for all $y \in [\frac{5\pi}{6},\pi]$. This is the lower bound to be used on the ends.

Finally, combining these, a lower bound obtained is $$
\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/6} \frac{\pi}{x+\pi}dx + \int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{5\frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\pi}{2x(x+\pi)}dx + \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\int_{5 \pi/6}^{\pi} \frac{\pi(\pi-x)}{x(x+\pi)}dx
$$

Following the same $\frac{\pi}{x(\pi+x)} = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+\pi}$ trick and computing the required integrals leads to a lower bound of $\approx 1.02$. Thus, we have shown that $$
1.49 \geq \pi\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\pi \sin x}{x(x+\pi)}dx \geq 1.02
$$

Where we only used the calculator to calculate some logarithms and bounds which were derived using , at most, the mean value theorem. All antiderivatives were explicitly found. The lesson here is the usage of these first-order bounds, and the recognition that the best way to estimate the required quantity is to replace $\sin x$ by a polynomial in $x$ in two end domains and a central domain.